# Getting UnknownHostKey exception despite setting STRICT_HOST_CHECKING in JSch

Tags: java, proxy, sftp, jsch

Getting Issue while execution below code while connecting session using java code.Try with all of the changes also Try with SFTPFileSystemConfigurationBuilder, But from that scenario I am not able to set the proxy server username and password.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ProxySOCKS5;

JSch js=new JSch();
   ProxySOCKS5 ph=new ProxySOCKS5(proxyServer,proxyPort);
   ph.setUserPasswd(proxyUN, proxyPass);
   com.jcraft.jsch.Session sessi=js.getSession(sftpUN, SFTPURL,SFTPPort);
   sessi.setPassword(sftpPassword);
   sessi.setProxy(ph);
   sessi.setConfig("STRICT_HOST_CHECKING", "no");

  //Getting Error
   sessi.connect();
   /*
    com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: proxyServer. RSA key fingerprint is XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX......
      at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:797)
      at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:342)
      at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
     */ 

    Channel ch=sessi.openChannel("sftp");
   ch.connect();
   ChannelSftp sftpCh= (ChannelSftp) ch;
   sftpCh.cd(remoteDirectory);
   File fileToTransfer= new File(localDirectory);
   sftpCh.put(new FileInputStream(fileToTransfer),"1.txt");
   sftpCh.disconnect();
   ch.disconnect();
   sessi.disconnect()
```

Comment: Where did you get the `STRICT_HOST_CHECKING` from?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with proxy.

There's no `STRICT_HOST_CHECKING` directive. There's `StrictHostKeyChecking`.

---

*Though note that you loose any security by using this directive. Make sure you understand what you are doing.*